# Eclipse Saving "Sort members" settings to repo

Tags: java, eclipse

I have an Eclipse project which relies on the Java Editor->Save Actions to produce correctly formatted code. The Eclipse project files are stored in repo. (It is outside of the scope of this question on how smart this practise is)

The problem is that one of the options in Save Actions is Sort Members. This is configurable only on global settings (i.e. Window->Preferences->Java->Appearance->Members Sort Order) and this project requires the "Sort members in same category by visibility" checkbox to be checked.

The default settings for Eclipse has that checkbox not checked (at least on latest versions), therefore if new developer (or existing using new fresh installation of eclipse) starts working on the project, the save actions (which is activated by default via settings from the repo) results having wrong order of methods.

I can write instructions about that in a README, but I was wondering is there any way to save that setting to the repo (also meaning it would be project-specific)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This setting is stored in the Eclipse JDT UI preferences.

These are stored in the workspace `.metadata/.plugins/org.eclipse.core.runtime/.settings` folder in the `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.prefs` file.

In that file the settings is the `org.eclipse.jdt.ui.enable.visibility.order` property.

So this cannot be project specific and it is not really possible to store this in a repository.

(Source code for the settings is in `org.eclipse.jdt.internal.ui.preferences.MembersOrderPreferencePage`)

Comment: I was afraid it would be so. Marking this as accepted.